# How can i start glassfish as a service

Tags: glassfish

I want to start `glassfish 3.1.2.2` automaticaly on system restart, so when i try to create a service using `create-service`, 2 files are created on my domain folder, `domain1Service.exe` and `domain1Service.xml`, but an error is displayed :
[image]
then when i try to start the service using `C:\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\bin\domain1Service.exe start`, i get the following error
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install the Glassfish service you have to start the `cmd` shell as Administrator.

Then you can run `create-service --name domain1` in the `asadmin` console.

You don't have to start the `domain1Service.exe` manually, Windows will do it for you.